# Torque on a wire loop

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, magnetic-fields, torque

[image]

I know how to find the magnetic dipole and solved it to be (10A)(0.005 m^2) = 0.05 in the -z direction. However, the next part of the question asks to find the magnitude and direction of the torque and this is where I get confused. I've attached my work below. The angle between the dipole and the mag. field I calculated as 150 degrees, so I got a net positive torque in the y direction. However, the answer key says its in the negative y direction. Am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this page in the site help](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more on what topics you can ask about here.

Comment: @JohnRennie I've literally worked out the entire question...my work is shown. I'm not asking you to give me answers considering I have the answer key. I'm asking for clarification if I did the steps correctly since they don't correspond with the answer key.

Comment: You can find the direction directly by the direction of $\vec m X \vec B$ by right hand thumb rule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The angle between $\mu$ and $\vec B$ is $210^\text{o}$ not $150^\text{o}$. We measure angle anti-clockwise from the initial to final vector. So in the cross product $\mu \times \vec{B}$, we measure the angle from $\mu$ to $\vec{B}$ anti-clockwise

Comment: Thanks! I had a feeling that my angle was off and the reason for me not getting a negative value. Thank you for clarifying this for me.